# Error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group'

Tags: c#

```
     private int[] runwayFee;

  public string GetMonthWithHighRevenue()
        {
            return ReturnMonth(runwayFee.ToString[GetIndexOfHighRevenue()]);
        } public int GetIndexOfHighRevenue()
    {
        int max = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i > runwayFee.Length; i++)
            if (runwayFee[i] > runwayFee[max])
                max = i;

        return max;
    }
```

Tried a million different options but keep getting errors with this line:

return ReturnMonth(runwayFee.ToString[GetIndexOfHighRevenue()]);

Comment: Every character in your example is telling the compiler something; you have got to learn what every character means and why it is there. You cannot learn this stuff through trial and error, there are simply too many permutations of characters to go through them all. And some of the permutations will compile but give you the wrong answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the `ToString()` and `[]` operators in the wrong place.

```
ReturnMonth(runwayFee[GetIndexOfHighRevenue()].ToString());
```

You were jamming a lot of code into one line, and that made it easy to get confused.

In these situations, a good strategy to use is to break it down into multiple lines of code:

```
    public string GetMonthWithHighRevenue()
    {
        int index = GetIndexOfHighRevenue();
        int highFee = runawayFee[index];
        string highFeeString = highFee.ToString();
        string month = ReturnMonth(highFeeString);
        return month;
    }
```

I don't know if that will work, because I don't know what parameter `ReturnMonth` expects. But if you break it down into multiple lines, the error will become more obvious to you.